# Facebook's Account Kit gets Cut off from Top Margins for iphone X

Tags: account-kit

I am using Facebook's accountKit to do phone verifications but one of the screens were cut off by the iphoneX nob.

I had to personally highlight the region that was cut off by the iPhone X's faceID/front camera nob.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was that I had **info.plist: View controller-based status bar appearance: NO**  in my info.plist file. When I removed that line from the info.plist, everything worked as expected.